# Can we balance $2$-powers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, discrepancy-theory

If a sequence of reals $-1<x_1,\dots,x_k<1$ satisfies

\begin{equation*}
        x_{i+1}=
        \begin{cases}
            2x_i, & \text{if } 2|x_i|<1 \\
            2x_i-2, & \text{if } 2x_i>1 \\
            2x_i+2, & \text{if } 2x_i<-1 \\
        \end{cases}
    \end{equation*}
for $i=1,\dots,k$,
where $x_{k+1}=x_1$, then is there a permutation $\pi$ of $\{1,\dots,k\}$ such that $0\le \sum_{i=1}^j x_{\pi(i)}<1$ for every $j$?

*Motivation.* The problem came up in a [recent joint work](https://doi.org/10.5817/CZ.MUNI.EUROCOMB23-044) with Gábor Damásdi, Nóra Frankl and János Pach.
This question is similar to Steinitz's theorem and to other vector balancing problems.
Indeed, it can be proved for any $x_i$'s satisfying the conditions of the conjecture, that $\sum_{i=1}^k x_i=0$.
Note that if the $x_i$'s are any sequence satisfying $\sum_{i=1}^k x_i=0$ and $|x_i|<1/2$ for every $i$, then one can easily find a permutation for which $0\le \sum_{i=1}^j x_{\pi(i)}<1$ for every $j$.
But without this bound, we have to exploit that $x_{i+1}=2x_i$, as otherwise there would be counterexamples (e.g., $0.6,0.6,0.6,-0.9,-0.9$).
Could it be that the statement is true because we always have many $i$'s such that $|x_i|<1/2$, and these can be used somehow to take care of the other $x_i$'s?
Some weaker versions, where $1$ is replaced with $1.2$, have been proved by others (unpublished).

Comment: Does the third case in the recurrence contain a typo?

Comment: @Fedor It did, thanks. (Ps. I also left a comment here for you about it, but for some strange reason it disappeared overnight, so let me try again.)

Comment: so, $x_i$ is just $2^{i-1}x_1$ modulo 2, where the remainder is chosen in $[-1,1)$, and $(2^k-1)x_1$ is divisible by 2, so the sequence is periodic, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: In the linked article, if I understand correctly, the identity $\sum_{i=1}^k x_i = 0$ is derived using a certain monochromatic $k$-gon, whose existence is only conjectural. Is this correct? Or is there some other proof for $\sum_i x_i  = 0$? It is easy to see that $\sum_i x_i$ is an even integer, so $\pi$ can only exist if $\sum_i x_i = 0$.

Comment: That is easy because $\sum_{i=1}^k x_i\equiv \sum_{i=1}^k 2x_i$, so it has to be zero.

Comment: @domotorp This only proves $\sum_{i=1}^k x_k \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$, i.e., the sum is an even integer.

Comment: @user42355, domotorph has understated it, there is equality between the two sums. The change of sign from $x_i$ to $x_{i+1}$ reflects whether $0$, $-2$ or $2$ has been added to $2x_i$ to yield $x_{i+1}$. While going through $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k, x_1$ there must be as many flips from positive to negative as from negative to positive. Therefore $\sum_{i=1}^k x_i = $ $\sum_{i=1}^k (2x_i + (0\text{ or }-2\text{ or }2)) = $ $\sum_{i=1}^k 2x_i + \sum_{i=1}^k(0\text{ or }-2\text{ or }2) = $ $\sum_{i=1}^k 2x_i + 0$.

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATED.** I've changed the verification strategy and computationally proved the statement for all $k\leq 30$, using the following randomized algorithm.

*Randomized algorithm.* For a given list of $k$ values of $x$'s sorted in increasing order, we set initially $s=0$, and at each of $k$ steps we identify the range of list elements that belong to the interval $[-s,1-s)$, select one of them, say $v$, randomly, remove it from the list, and add $v$ to $s$ (thus keeping $s$ in the interval $[0,1)$). The algorithm succeeds if we are able to make all $k$ steps, and fails otherwise (when at some step there are no suitable elements in the list).

From Fedor's observation it follows that for a fixed $k$, we can restrict our attention to values $x_1 = \frac{m}{2^k-1}$ for $m\equiv 2\pmod4$ in the interval $[2,2^k-2]$ and the sequences of $x_i$ emerging from them. For each such sequence (sorted in increasing order), we run the randomized algorithm multiple times until it succeeds.

It's worth to note that for a fixed $k$, the average number of algorithm runs (over all $m$) used in my computation was about $k/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Fedor Petrov's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/462541/can-we-balance-2-powers#comment1200317_462541) shows than for each $k$ there are only finitely many cases for $x_1$ to check, so I wrote a program to do this. The positive answer is already obtained for all natural $k\le 10$.
Almost most of the considered sequences $(x_i)$ can be balanced by the following algorithm.
Fist pick the maximal positive $x_i$ and at each next step pick some allowed remaining $x_i$ with the maximal absolute value. So now I am thinking how to balance a few remaining exceptional sequences.

Comment: I'm sorry if I forgot to mention in the question (in the paper we do) that we also wrote a computer code and checked many cases using similar ad hoc ideas.